# C# Generic method and dynamic type problem

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, types

I have a generic method declared as follow :

```
public void Duplicate<EntityType>() { ... }
```

So, generally to use it I simply need to do say :

```
myObject.Duplicate<int>()
```

But here, what I'd like to do is pass the type by a variable, but it doesn't work, here is how I try to do this :

```
Type myType = anObject.GetType();
myObject.Duplicate<myType>();
```

If someone can help me ?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use reflection, basically:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(...).GetMethod("Duplicate");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(myType);
generic.Invoke(myObject, null);
```

Comment: One of these days I'm going to follow your advice to post then revise. Beaten to the punch once again for double checking a method name. :) +1

Comment: Should do the trick, I will test it. Thank

Comment: Hey, @Jon, I know your answer dates back to about 5 years ago and maybe `MethodInfo.Invoke` method used to have an overload (if not the only one) that took one argument but right now that's not the case. We need to pass at least `null` if the method to invoke doesn't take any parameters. And there's another case where there might be overloads of the `Duplicate` method which will throw AmbiguousMatchException. I'm sure you know it but I just wanted to add my two cents anyway.

Comment: @MikayilAbdullayev: Added the `null` argument.

Answer (score 4):

Where you have the type as a variable you don't really have a good candidate for generic methods, especially as your method returns nothing.

You would be better off with:

```
public void Duplicate(Type entityType) { ... }
```

Then your code becomes:

```
Type myType = anObject.GetType();
myObject.Duplicate(myType);
```

You can use Jon Skeet's (correct) answer to call your method by reflection, but I can't see what you gain by this method being generic.

The purpose of generics is to preserve the type - so that you don't have to box/unbox value types and so on.

However your duplicate method has no return (it's a `void`) and no input parameters. Essentially the only input is the type-parameter. This means that somewhere inside your generic method you're probably doing something like:

```
public void Duplicate<EntityType>() 
{
 ...
 Type inputType = typeof(EntityType); 
 ...
}
```

In that case you're not gaining anything by `EntityType` being a generic type-parameter rather than a regular input parameter, and you're adding the need for awkward and slow reflection when you don't know the input at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a standard method taking a Type as an argument:

```
myobject.Duplicate(myType);
```

or you can try with reflection, something like:

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = typeof(TypeOfMyObject).GetMethod("Duplicate<>");
MethodInfo constructedMethodInfo = mi.MakeGenericMethod(new type[] {myType});
constructedMethodInfo.Invoke(myObject, new object[] {});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear of the exact function of Duplicate(), but the following example works when your type you want to pass in to Duplicate() is a class or an int.

Essentially, don't pass in a type, pass in an example object. This test method illustrates the call (two tests in one method)

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var myObject = new AnObject { AString = "someString" };

        var myOtherObject = new AnotherObject();
        var newObject = myObject.Duplicate(myOtherObject);
        Assert.IsTrue(newObject.AString=="someString");

        var newObject2 = myObject.Duplicate(1);
        Assert.IsTrue(newObject2 is Int32);
    }
```

The Duplicate() method has a type parameter linked to the example object, but does not need to be called with the type given as a parameter, it infers it from the example object.

Here is the class with a Duplicate() method:

```
public class AnObject
{
    public string AString { get; set; }

    public T Duplicate<T>(T exampleObject)
        where T: new()
    {
        var newInstance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        // do some stuff here to newInstance based on this AnObject
        if (typeof (T) == typeof (AnotherObject))
        {
            var another = newInstance as AnotherObject;
            if(another!=null)
                another.AString = this.AString;
        }

        return newInstance;
    }
}
```

To complete the picture, this is the AnotherObject class.

```
public class AnotherObject
{
    public string AString { get; set; }
}
```

This code may have some problems inside the Duplicate() method when the type passed in is a value type like **int**. It depends on what you want Duplicate() to do with the int (you may have to be pass it in as a nullable int).

It works well for reference types (classes).

Comment: Actually, if you're going down the generic route, I think's Keith's reply is a better version than mine. No example type is required. I'm assuming it works, and that you don't need a return value.

Comment: I'm assuming that Duplicate() is intended to return a clone of the type passed in, but your question indicates there is no return value.